# Flexslider to load different slide on each time the page reloads

Tags: html, jquery, flexslider

I am using this flexslider plugin for one of the projects with 3 videos and text over them.
My issue is that sometimes when the page reloads it loads the same slide again.
Is there any way to make sure that a new slide is loaded on page load? I have changed it to random, but the issue with that in some cases loads the same slide multiple times. Ideally we would have new content each time the page reloads.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Awesome-Fully-Responsive-jQuery-Slider-FlexSlider.html

Any suggestions on how can I tweak the script to load the next one on page load. No sliding effect needed.

Thank you.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
   animationLoop: false,
  randomize: true,
  controlNav: false,
  touch: true,
  directionNav: false,
   smoothHeight: true, 
    slideshow: false
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
    <video autoplay="" class="FullVideo" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="auto"><source src="/Portals/0/Videos/Pexels1-Nature.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ContentOverlay">
    SOME CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <video autoplay="" class="FullVideo" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="auto"><source src="/Portals/0/Videos/Pexels2-Tree.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ContentOverlay">
    SOME CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <video autoplay="" class="FullVideo" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="auto"><source src="/Portals/0/Videos/Pexelsvideo-ladymp4.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ContentOverlay">
SOME CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Store that in local storage the slide loaded last time or you can store a que in local storage and current position in que and then change slides according to que on reloads

Comment: instead of randomise, use `startAt` and localstorage

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I am not a javascript whizz - will the following code work?


`code
window.localStorage.setItem('flexslider li'); 
$(function() { var value = localStorage.getItem("flexslider li"); 
if (value) { $('.flexslider').flexslider({ 
animationLoop: false, 
startAt: 0, 
controlNav: false, 
touch: true, 
directionNav: false, 
smoothHeight: true, 
slideshow: false }); 
} 
});
`